# how to boot into a generic kernel

Tags: kernel

I have the following installed:

```
root@system:~$ ls /lib/modules
5.15.0-100-generic  5.15.0-1051-kvm
```

I wish to boot into `5.15.0-100-generic` from the default `5.15.0-1051-kvm` on reboot.
How do I do it?